# What does "Add. Or. 742" mean in this citation referencing the India Office Library of the British Library?

Tags: citations

In a book about the East India Company that has a list of illustrations, the source of one is listed as "The British Library, London Add. Or. 742."  A footnote referencing this watercolor is later included as the following: "Add. Or. 742, India Office Library."

Does anyone know the meaning of the abbreviations "Add. Or." and what 742 is, in this context? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"[Add. Or. 742](https://searcharchives.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/display.do?tabs=detailsTab&ct=display&fn=search&doc=IAMS040-003270869&indx=1&recIds=IAMS040-003270869&recIdxs=0&elementId=0&renderMode=poppedOut&displayMode=full&frbrVersion=&frbg=&&dscnt=0&scp.scps=scope%3A%28BL%29&mode=Basic&vid=IAMS_VU2&srt=rank&tab=local&vl(freeText0)=Add%20Or%20742&dum=true&dstmp=1650655178819)" is a catalogue reference to the item in collection of the British Library.

I think "Add" stands for "additional", as in ["Additional Manuscripts"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additional_manuscripts), which are reference by "Add MS". There is also "Add Ch", which seem to be charters. I'm not certain what "Add Or", but it might refer to ["Orient"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orient), as in the (far) east. The references I've look at all fell in that category.

"742" makes it the 742nd addition to that part of the collection.